# Inner Join a table then with var of this table join other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to Inner Join a table then with var of this table joined, join other table.

```
SELECT
dc_orders.reference,
dc_orders.email,
dc_orders.ip,
dc_orders.`data`,
dc_orders.hora,
dc_orders.nick,
dc_orders.nome,
dc_orders.pacote_id,
dc_orders.extras,
dc_orders.cupom,
dc_orders.`status`,
dc_orders.receptor,
dc_orders.activation_code,
dc_orders.metodo,
dc_orders.preco,
dc_orders.order_id,

pacotes.nome,
pacotes.nome_exibicao,
pacotes.servidor,

servers.nome,
servers.nome_exibicao

FROM dc_orders
INNER JOIN dc_pacotes pacotes ON dc_orders.pacote_id = pacotes.id
INNER JOIN dc_servers servers ON pacotes.servidor = servers.id


WHERE dc_orders.reference = 'referencecode';
```

*I tried to use union and not work to
I think it's possible to have to use another "JOIN" like RIGHT, LEFT or FULL

Comment: what do you meant by Inner Join a table then with var of this table join other table? is it, result of your current query joining another new table?

Answer (score 0):

Easy i discover the problem, pacotes.servidor is not the same servers.id, i changed to right key and worked